# Highcharts: setSize on each Multiple chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In Multiple Highcharts: I'm trying to use the setSize function on individual charts where I have multiple charts on a page and then a button changes the size of one chart. This is only an example but there would be a button for each chart.

However I am getting the error "Object has not method 'setSize'.

Some how I am not calling the right object on this page and I had this working once before.
Before I used something like window[obj], but that no longer works, not sure what I broke.

See jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/no1uknow/42rWu/10/

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //first chart in result window
        $('button#setme').click(function() {
            alert("setting");
            $("#container_chartFreqAtaTailNum").setSize(200, 200, false);
            alert("set");
        });

        // second chart in Result window
        $('button#setme2').click(function() {
            alert("setting");
            $("#container_chartGroupByFlightHours").setSize(200, 200, false);
            alert("set");
        });

        var container_chartCorrectiveAction = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartCorrectiveAction',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 195

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Corrective Action'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Sub-ATA () / ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['No Defects Found-Fastener-Loose / Displaced'],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Action'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Count',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Count';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: [{
                name: 'Heavy',
                total: '0',
                data: [null]
                },{
                name: 'Intermediate',
                total: '0',
                data: [null]
                },{
                name: 'Line',
                total: '0',
                data: [null]
                },{
                name: 'Lite',
                total: '1',
                data: [1]
                }]
                });


        var container_chartAtaFleetAvg = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartAtaFleetAvg',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 185

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fleet Average'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Fleet Average'],
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Average',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Average';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: [{
                name: 'Intermediate',
                total: '0.35',
                data: [0.35]
                },{
                name: 'Lite',
                total: '0.3',
                data: [0.30]
                },{
                name: 'Heavy',
                total: '0.1',
                data: [0.10]
                }]
                });


        var container_chartSubAtaFleetAvg = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartSubAtaFleetAvg',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 175

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fleet Average'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Sub-ATA () / ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Fleet Average'],
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Average',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Average';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: [{
                name: 'Heavy',
                total: '0.1',
                data: [0.10]
                },{
                name: 'Lite',
                total: '0.05',
                data: [0.05]
                }]
                });



            var container_chartAtaFlightDelay = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container_chartAtaFlightDelay',
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Flight Delays'
                },
                subtitle: {
                        text: 'ATA (20)'
                    },
                xAxis: [{
                    categories: []

                }],
                yAxis: [
                    { 
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value +' Mins';
                            },
                            style: { 
                                color: '#89A54E',
                                width: '5000px',
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Minutes',
                            style: {
                                color: '#89A54E'
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    { 
                        title: {
                            text: 'Delays',
                            style: { color: '#4572A7'}
                        },
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value +' Delays';
                            },
                            style: {color: '#4572A7'}
                        },
                        opposite: true
                    }
                ],
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return ''+ this.x +': '+ this.y + (this.series.name == 'Minutes' ? ' Minutes' : ' Delays');
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true
                },
                credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                series: [{
                            name: 'Delays',
                            color: '#4572A7',
                            type: 'column',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            data: []
                        },{
                            name: 'Minutes',
                            color: '#89A54E',
                            type: 'spline',
                            data: []
                        }]
            });


            var container_chartSubAtaFlightDelay = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container_chartSubAtaFlightDelay',
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Flight Delays'
                },
                subtitle: {
                        text: 'Sub-ATA () / ATA (20)'
                    },
                xAxis: [{
                    categories: []

                }],
                yAxis: [
                    { 
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value +' Mins';
                            },
                            style: { 
                                color: '#89A54E',
                                width: '5000px',
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Minutes',
                            style: {
                                color: '#89A54E'
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    { 
                        title: {
                            text: 'Delays',
                            style: { color: '#4572A7'}
                        },
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value +' Delays';
                            },
                            style: {color: '#4572A7'}
                        },
                        opposite: true
                    }
                ],
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return ''+ this.x +': '+ this.y + (this.series.name == 'Minutes' ? ' Minutes' : ' Delays');
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true
                },
                credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                series: [{
                            name: 'Delays',
                            color: '#4572A7',
                            type: 'column',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            data: []
                        },{
                            name: 'Minutes',
                            color: '#89A54E',
                            type: 'spline',
                            data: []
                        }]
            });

        var container_chartFreqAtaTailNum = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartFreqAtaTailNum',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 275

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Frequency by Tail Number'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['213','442','792'],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Tail Number'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Count',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Count';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: [{
                name: 'Heavy',
                total: '2',
                data: [null,null,2]
                },{
                name: 'Intermediate',
                total: '7',
                data: [null,3,4]
                },{
                name: 'Line',
                total: '0',
                data: [null,null,null]
                },{
                name: 'Lite',
                total: '6',
                data: [2,2,2]
                }]
                });


        var container_chartSubAtaDelayCode = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartSubAtaDelayCode',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 155

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Frequency By Delay Code'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Sub-ATA () / ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: [],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Delay Code'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Minutes',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Minutes';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: []
                });


        var container_chartAtaDelayCode = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartAtaDelayCode',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 155

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Frequency By Delay Code'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: [],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Delay Code'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Minutes',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Minutes';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: []
                });


        var container_chartSubAtaLocation = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartSubAtaLocation',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 235

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Frequency By Location'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Sub-ATA () / ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['PAE','STL'],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Location'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Count',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Count';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: [{
                name: 'Heavy',
                total: '2',
                data: [2,null]
                },{
                name: 'Intermediate',
                total: '0',
                data: [null,null]
                },{
                name: 'Line',
                total: '0',
                data: [null,null]
                },{
                name: 'Lite',
                total: '1',
                data: [null,1]
                }]
                });


        var container_chartAtaLocation = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartAtaLocation',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 395

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Frequency By Location'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['HOU','ISP','MDW','PAE','PHX','STL'],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Location'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Count',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Count';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: [{
                name: 'Heavy',
                total: '2',
                data: [null,null,null,2,null,null]
                },{
                name: 'Intermediate',
                total: '7',
                data: [3,null,2,null,2,null]
                },{
                name: 'Line',
                total: '0',
                data: [null,null,null,null,null,null]
                },{
                name: 'Lite',
                total: '4',
                data: [null,1,1,null,null,2]
                }]
                });


        var container_chartAtaFreqBySubAta = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartAtaFreqBySubAta',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 315

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Frequency By Sub ATA'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['DOCUMENTATION (No. 5)','REPAIR AND REPLACEMENT (No. 10)','INSPECTION / CHECK (No. 20)','SPECIFICATIONS AND MATERIALS (No. 30)'],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Sub ATA'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Count',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Count';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: [{
                name: 'Heavy',
                total: '2',
                data: [null,null,2,null]
                },{
                name: 'Intermediate',
                total: '3',
                data: [null,null,null,3]
                },{
                name: 'Line',
                total: '0',
                data: [null,null,null,null]
                },{
                name: 'Lite',
                total: '6',
                data: [2,3,1,null]
                }]
                });


        var container_chartFreqSubAtaTailNum = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_chartFreqSubAtaTailNum',

                        type: 'bar',
                        height: 235

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Frequency by Tail Number'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Sub-ATA () / ATA (20)'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['442','792'],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Tail Number'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                width: '12000px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Count',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' Count';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            pointWidth:10,
                            groupPadding: .05,
                            shadow: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        floating: false,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        shadow: true,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:12px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">   Total: ' + this.options.total + '</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: { 
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    series: [{
                name: 'Heavy',
                total: '2',
                data: [null,2]
                },{
                name: 'Intermediate',
                total: '0',
                data: [null,null]
                },{
                name: 'Line',
                total: '0',
                data: [null,null]
                },{
                name: 'Lite',
                total: '1',
                data: [1,null]
                }]
```

// etc..

```
        });
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be:

```
$("#container_chartFreqAtaTailNum").highcharts().setSize(200, 200, false);
```

So it will use Highcharts object to set size, not jQuery object.